# How to make SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics work?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I can't make SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics work, it always return a hashtable of 18 elements that are all zeros.

What I want to do : In my test environnent, I want to add a header for each httpresponse with the number of sql commands that were executed during the request processing.

My app is only (Rest) webservices, I have one sql connection par request ( One NHibernate session per request ).

After the request is processed, I do :

```
var connection = statelessSession.NHSession.Connection as ReliableSqlDbConnection;
if (connection != null)
    queries += Convert.ToInt32(connection.ReliableConnection.Current.RetrieveStatistics()["Prepares"]);
```

The number is always 0, and when I break on this line, I see that all numbers are zeros.

After the session is opened, I do :

```
var ret = module.OpenSession();
var connection = (ret.Connection as ReliableSqlDbConnection);
if(connection != null)
{
  connection.ReliableConnection.Current.StatisticsEnabled =true;
  ret.CreateSQLQuery("SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON;").ExecuteUpdate();
  connection.ReliableConnection.Current.ResetStatistics();
}
return ret;
```

I use https://github.com/MRCollective/NHibernate.SqlAzure because in production I'm using sql azure, but in local I have an instance of Sql Server 2014 Developer Edition.

For my database, I have :
Auto create statistics true
Auto update statistics true

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was that NHibernate opens a new connection for each request, this is why I was loosing the statistics each time.